# Argo Workflow with host file config

Tags: cloud, argo-workflows

I'm planning to use rclone in an Argo Workflow. The docker command to run and mount the configuration file is:

```
docker run --rm \
-v $(pwd)/config:/config/rclone \
rclone/rclone \
listremotes
```

This works fine. However what is the best approach to mount the `$(pwd)/config` into the workflow container?. I have something like this:

```
      container:
        image: rclone/rclone:latest
        args: ["listremotes"]
```

This gives:
`NOTICE: Config file "/config/rclone/rclone.conf" not found - using defaults`

This works fine as well but need to hardcode the config:

```
(...)
- name: write-message
      container:
        image: alpine:latest
        command: [sh, -c]
        args:
          [
           "echo writting file; echo CONFIG_HERE... | tee /config/rclone/rclone.conf",
          ]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: workdir
            mountPath: /config/rclone

- name: rclone-listremotes
      container:
        image: rclone/rclone:latest
        args: ["listremotes"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: workdir
            mountPath: /config/rclone
```

How can I pass a config file from the host, instead of write the config directly?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you add your `volumes` specification?

Comment: It's been a few days since you asked, so I'll offer some ideas. 1) You could use a configmap to define the config file and then mount it in the necessary step. 2) You could use a raw Argo artifact to drop the config into the step.